# array multiplication having different sizes

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to understand multiplication of two arrays which have different shapes. According to my understanding rows of d array should be equal to column of a array.

```
a = np.arange(3*2).reshape(3,2)
b= np.arange(3)
d = b[:,None]
c = a*d
```

Comment: What is the question? You can't reshape `np.arange(3*2)` to `(10,2)`

Comment: oh sorry I have edited the code

Comment: So what is the question? If you want to understand the result you should read about matrix multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication is a broad term in numpy. If you refer to element wise multiplication, use * if the arrays are equal shape or [np.multiply](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) in general, if you refer to matrix like multiplication, use [np.matmul](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html). Check the syntax and examples in the links.